# How can I verify if my IP address in Ubuntu was set statically or dynamically?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 and would like to know if my IP address for the network connection is set statically or dynamically. `cat /etc/network/interfaces` is not especially helpful as it only shows

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Any other way to get this information?

Comment: Atleast in my case static means router gives me a static IP by DHCP, may not be easy to distinguish from dynamic

Comment: But the IP address is 'either' statically allocated, i.e. does not change after logins, or is dynamically allocated, i.e. may change after log-in. This has to be configured somewhere, and therefore some information must be found in some files. But which one, and what contents?

Comment: in my case, in the router.

Comment: @Karthik: I do not use a router in my case. The machine is connected to the LAN directly (company LAN system).

Comment: yes, and before you go to internet you will pass a router. Similarly either a DHCP server or the same router might be incharge of granting you your IP via DHCP im guessing.

Comment: The "company LAN system" is the router.

Comment: For what its worth, you should be able to see in network manager (or equivalent if they have replaced it) setting whether it is static IP or DHCP

Comment: @Alex pls see http://www.liberiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/1029141aa483_8FD2/natty_windows_static_ip_7_thumb.png, the "Method" field is what i am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the long chain of comments.

Important point to note is that when you say static IP, it could mean static IP from clients point of view or static IP from routers point of view. So from clients side, they would be `static IP` vs `curiously static dynamic IP`.

If you are on a company LAN, it is all the more likely it is the latter, though could be former as well.

If you are interested in only the former (pure client side static IP), you should be able to find it from `/etc/network/interfaces` (not sure why you are not able to see), and from network manager GUI in Ubuntu, which is accessed by *System Settings* -> *Network* -> click *Options* button, as shown below:

[image: this image]